# vb .net access json information

Tags: json, vb.net

I have the following json output:

```
{
   "id":"354asda-asd435544-35438738fd",
   "oid":"354asda-asd435544-35438738fd-asdasd1212",
   "mids":[
      476252
   ],
   "name":"This is my name",
   "language":"en",
   "released":"2020-01-24",
   "url":"https://myownurl",
   "url2":"https://myownurl2",
   "image":true,
   "image_url":{
      "small":"https://myownurl/img_sm.jpg",
      "large":"https://myownurl/img_lg.jpg",
      "png":"https://myownurl/img_sm.png",
   },
...
}
```

I'm trying to access this information, but getting some trouble with it, with the image_url property.

```
Dim selected As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem()
Dim splited() As String = selected.Split(" - ")

Dim card As String = ListBox2.SelectedItem()
Dim cardsplit() As String = card.Split(" - ")

Dim uriString As String = "https://myownapi/" & splited(0) & "/" & cardsplit(0)

Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(New Uri(uriString))
Dim JSON_Response As String = New StreamReader(Request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

Dim JSON_Obj1 As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSON_Response)
TextBox2.Text = JSON_Response.ToString
Dim Test1 As String = JSON_Obj1("image_url")
TextBox1.Text = Test1("large")
```

How can I properly access all this information, including information inside those brackets [ ] and { }?
Thanks.

Comment: `TextBox1.Text = JSON_Obj1("image_url")("large").ToString()` or `TextBox1.Text = JSON_Obj1("mids")(0).ToString()`. Which requires `Option Strict Off`. You should probably deserialize that JSON to a class structure. It would be much simpler to handle it. Are you forced to use JavaScriptSerializer?

Comment: You could paste your JSON here: [JsonUtils](https://jsonutils.com/) (since it can provide VB.Net classes) and deserialize using the class you input in the `[Class Name]` box as the `RootClass` class object in `New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of RootClass)(json)`

Comment: @Jimi I've already tried JSON_Obj1("image_url")("large").ToString() but keeps telling me the key isn't present in the dictionary. I'm not forced to use JavaScriptSerializer. Do you suggest any lib to do this work? I've saw newtonsoft json, but doesn't have vb .net documentation...

Comment: Note that this: `JSON_Obj1("image_url")("large")` works if the JSON you posted here actually represents the real JSON. If you have that exception, than what you posted here is not the complete JSON object (what you posted is also not a valid JSON, per se, but it requires small corrections to validate). -- [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (Newtonsoft.Json - available as a NuGet Package) is commonly used to handle JSON transactions. Or `System.Text.Json` (.Net Core). `JavaScriptSerializer` can still be used. Test the utility I linked.