# VB. NET DeserializeObject() check if key exists

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a jSON Object that may contain a Key.
If the key is not present, it outputs an error. How can I check if the key exists before trying to get it?

```
Dim JSON_Obj1 As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSON_Response)
```

I've tried some things like:

```
If JSON_Obj1("image_uris")("png").ToString() IsNot DBNull.Value Then
```

Or even:

```
If JSON_Obj1("image_uris")("png").ToString() IsNot Nothing Then
```

But nothing seems to work. Any thoughts in this? It's even possible or I need to work with any lib that have this feature?

Comment: Already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800422/vb-net-access-json-information): deserialize to a class model, then access the resulting classes' properties as usual. If you need help in deserializing this JSON, you need to post the JSON (all of it, not just the section you're interested in).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ContainsKey method for this.
Please note that the keys must be tested one at a time from the root and down.
If you otherwise apply the ContainsKey method to a non existing key you will get an exception.
From your example it will look like the following:

```
If JSON_Obj1.ContainsKey("image_uris") AndAlso JSON_Obj1("image_uris").ContainsKey("png") Then
    'do whatever
End If
```

Hope this helps.